# Group the items related to 10 digit key?

Tags: javascript

```
    This has to be grouped using logic since it has large number of item.statically giving values using j query wont work for me.
```

This is array of items.Based on ID i need to format it in form of a tree

```
    [{"ID":"0200000000", "Name":"a"},
     {"ID":"0201000000", "Name":"b"},
     {"ID":"0201010000", "Name":"c",},
     {"ID":"0201010100", "Name":"d", },
     {"ID":"0201010200", "Name":"e",},
     {"ID":"0201010300", "Name":"f",},
     {"ID":"0300000000", "Name":"g"},
     {"ID":"0301000000", "Name":"h"},
     {"ID":"0301010000", "Name":"i"},
     {"ID":"0301010100", "Name":"j"},
     {"ID":"0301010200", "Name":"k"},
     {"ID":"0301010300", "Name":"l"},
     {"ID":"0301010400", "Name":"m"},
     {"ID":"0400000000", "Name":"n"}]

    This should be the result.It is based on the ID from the array.
   I am using j query in front end and java script in back end   
    -a
       -b
          -c
          -d
          -e
          -f
    -g
       -h
          -i
          -j
          -k
          -l    
          -m
    -n




  for (i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
      item2[i] = resultArray1[i]
      item5[i] = resultArray[i + 1]
      item[i] = resultArray1[i].split("", 10);
      item1[i] = resultArray1[i + 1].split("", 10);

        if (item[i][1] != item1[i][1]) {

          if (k == 1) {
            item6.push(item5[i])
          }

          if (k == 3) {
            item6.push(item5[i])    
          }

          if (k == 5) {

            item6.push(item5[i])
          }

          if (k == 7) {

            item6.push(item5[i])
          }

          if (k == 9) {

            item6.push(item5[i])
          }

     }
```

I tried matching and giving condition by splitting the ID.
Now the output is single dimensional array .if it can be multidimensional it would work.I am new to development.Can anyone help?? I cant do this manually.

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us? We won't code for you ...

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: List these items how? You want an array with sub arrays, a DOM representation with `<ul><l>...` as required, a simple text output with fixed width spacing in a span/div, etc..? It is very unclear at this stage what it is you want exactly. How do you want us to determine the child relation ships, I assume it is in the number? What parsing logic is to be used on that number?

Answer (score 0):

For sorted data without gaps, you could look just for the last double zero and use this item as level. Then build an object with a helper array for the levels.

```js
var array = [{ ID: "0200000000", Name: "a" }, { ID: "0201000000", Name: "b" }, { ID: "0201010000", Name: "c", }, { ID: "0201010100", Name: "d", }, { ID: "0201010200", Name: "e", }, { ID: "0201010300", Name: "f", }, { ID: "0300000000", Name: "g" }, { ID: "0301000000", Name: "h" }, { ID: "0301010000", Name: "i" }, { ID: "0301010100", Name: "j" }, { ID: "0301010200", Name: "k" }, { ID: "0301010300", Name: "l" }, { ID: "0301010400", Name: "m" }, { ID: "0400000000", Name: "n" }],
    result = [],
    levels = [{ children: result }];

array.forEach(({ ID, Name }) => {
    var path = ID.match(/(..)/g).concat('00'),
        level = path.findIndex(s => s === '00') - 1;

    levels[level].children = levels[level].children || [];
    levels[level].children.push(levels[level + 1] = { Name });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: var array = [{ ID: "0200000000", Name: "a" }, { ID: "0201000000", Name: "b" }, { ID: "0201010000", Name: "c", }, { ID: "0201010100", Name: "d", }, { ID: "0201010200", Name: "e", }, { ID: "0201010300", Name: "f", }, { ID: "0300000000", Name: "g" }, { ID: "0301000000", Name: "h" }, { ID: "0301010000", Name: "i" }, { ID: "0301010100", Name: "j" }, { ID: "0301010200", Name: "k" }, { ID: "0301010300", Name: "l" }, { ID: "0301010400", Name: "m" }, { ID: "0400000000", Name: "n" }],

Comment: what is with that array?

Comment: can we display this as a tree with collapse option?like fist only main nodes will be visible and if we click on those main nodes child node will be displayed?using j query or java script.

Comment: please help out @NinaScholz

Comment: actually i do not know, how the wanted collapsible tree should look like. maybe you add ana ttempt of it, or better ask a new question about creating the wanted html structure.